# GeometricScene is slow and does not find an answer to a visually obvious problem for many points

Tags: synthetic-geometry

I'm trying to use GeometricScene to visualize a finite patch of a periodic tiling of triangles and rhombi.  When I require the rhombi to be squares (using "Regular" property on the Polygons), Mathematica can find the answer (using RandomInstance) in seconds.  Relaxing the requirement to be a square introduces only one unconstrained parameter, but Mathematica takes a long time to not find an answer.  Is this because I could have structured my code better, e.g. with GeometricSteps?

Below is the result for the case using squares, and the code that generated it. However, when I replace the GeometricAssertion of "Regular" with "Equilateral", it doesn't return an answer.

[image]

```
    RandomInstance[
 GeometricScene[{a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h, i, j, k, l, m, n, o, p, q, r,
    s, t, u, v, w, x, y, z, aa, bb, cc, dd, ee, ff, gg, hh, ii, jj},
  {
   s1 = Style[Polygon[{e, d, b, a}], Red],
   s2 = Style[Polygon[{a, f, h, g}], Red],
   s3 = Style[Polygon[{e, i, j, k}], Red],
   s4 = Style[Polygon[{i, g, l, m}], Red],
   s5 = Style[Polygon[{o, h, q, r}], Red],
   s6 = Style[Polygon[{l, o, s, t}], Red],
   s7 = Style[Polygon[{n, m, u, v}], Red],
   s8 = Style[Polygon[{j, n, w, x}], Red],
   s9 = Style[Polygon[{c, b, bb, dd}], Red],
   s10 = Style[Polygon[{y, f, c, ee}], Red],
   s11 = Style[Polygon[{aa, d, p, ff}], Red],
   s12 = Style[Polygon[{p, k, z, gg}], Red],
   
   t1 = Triangle[{a, b, c}],
   t2 = Triangle[{a, c, f}],
   t3 = Style[Triangle[{a, g, e}], Green],
   t4 = Style[Triangle[{e, g, i}], Green],
   t5 = Triangle[{g, h, l}],
   t6 = Triangle[{e, k, d}],
   t7 = Triangle[{i, m, n}],
   t8 = Triangle[{j, i, n}],
   t9 = Triangle[{l, h, o}],
   t10 = Triangle[{d, k, p}],
   t11 = Triangle[{h, f, q}],
   t12 = Triangle[{q, f, y}],
   t13 = Triangle[{m, l, t}],
   t14 = Triangle[{m, t, u}],
   t15 = Triangle[{k, j, z}],
   t16 = Triangle[{j, x, z}],
   t17 = Triangle[{b, d, aa}],
   t18 = Triangle[{b, aa, bb}],
   t19 = Triangle[{o, r, cc}],
   t20 = Triangle[{s, o, cc}],
   t21 = Triangle[{p, gg, hh}],
   t22 = Triangle[{p, hh, ff}],
   t23 = Triangle[{c, dd, ee}],
   t24 = Triangle[{ee, dd, ii}],
   t25 = Triangle[{n, v, w}],
   t26 = Triangle[{w, v, jj}],
   
   GeometricAssertion[{t1, t2, t3, t4, t5, t6, t7, t8, t9, t10, t11, 
     t12, t13, t14, t15, t16, t17, t18, t19, t20, t21, t22, t23, t24, 
     t25, t26}, "Equilateral", "Clockwise"],
   GeometricAssertion[{s1, s2, s3, s4, s5, s6, s7, s8, s9, s10, s11, 
     s12}, "Regular", "Clockwise"]
   }
  ]]
```

It does work, however, if I use a smaller tiling, e.g.:

[image]